# How to select only 3 row after some label in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this:

```
Month   Time          Label
Apr     19:10:11      Query
Apr     19:10:11      Not Command
Apr     19:10:12      Not Command
Apr     19:10:12      Sending
Apr     19:10:13      Not Command
Apr     19:10:13      Not Command
Apr     19:10:14      Not Command
Apr     19:10:14      Not Command
Apr     19:10:14      Answer
Apr     19:10:14      Not Command
Apr     19:10:15      Not Command
Apr     19:10:15      Not Command
```

I want to make the table into every label that is not equal to `Not Command` like `Query`, `Sending` and `Answer`. I want to select always 3 line after that label. This is the result that i wanted

```
Month   Time          Label
Apr     19:10:11      Query
Apr     19:10:11      Not Command
Apr     19:10:12      Not Command
Apr     19:10:12      Sending
Apr     19:10:13      Not Command
Apr     19:10:13      Not Command
Apr     19:10:14      Answer
Apr     19:10:14      Not Command
Apr     19:10:15      Not Command
```

Is it possible? i have idea to make new label that iterate number when meet label that not command but i don't know how. So maybe there is a better way to solve this. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think select `3` or less rows create mask by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and filter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby(df['Label'].ne('Not Command').cumsum()).cumcount().lt(3)]
print (df)
   Month      Time        Label
0    Apr  19:10:11        Query
1    Apr  19:10:11  Not Command
2    Apr  19:10:12  Not Command
3    Apr  19:10:12      Sending
4    Apr  19:10:13  Not Command
5    Apr  19:10:13  Not Command
8    Apr  19:10:14       Answer
9    Apr  19:10:14  Not Command
10   Apr  19:10:15  Not Command
```

If need select 3 rows if exist 3 or more rows, else not select add new mask with filtering by[`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) with bitwise `AND` - `&`:

```
print (df)
   Month      Time        Label
0    Apr  19:10:11        Query
1    Apr  19:10:11  Not Command <- only 2 rows - omited
2    Apr  19:10:12      Sending
3    Apr  19:10:13  Not Command
4    Apr  19:10:13  Not Command
5    Apr  19:10:14  Not Command
6    Apr  19:10:14  Not Command
7    Apr  19:10:14       Answer
8    Apr  19:10:14  Not Command
9    Apr  19:10:15  Not Command
10   Apr  19:10:15  Not Command

s = df['Label'].ne('Not Command').cumsum()

df = df[s.map(s.value_counts()).ge(3) & s.groupby(s).cumcount().lt(3)]
print (df)
  Month      Time        Label
2   Apr  19:10:12      Sending
3   Apr  19:10:13  Not Command
4   Apr  19:10:13  Not Command
7   Apr  19:10:14       Answer
8   Apr  19:10:14  Not Command
9   Apr  19:10:15  Not Command
```